# stop booting from external disk

Tags: boot

I have an external 2tb disk that is sometimes connected when I start my computer. The system hen tries to boot from the external drive because it is set in the BIOS to boot from usb. I want to keep that BIOS setup, because I sometimes need to boot from usb.

But how can I setup the external drive, not to boot or to forward to the internal drive boot?

Comment: If the BIOS is set to boot from USB then that should be the expected result. You BIOS cannot guess whether you want to actually boot from that USB or any other drive. So, just change the BIOS setting and use the one time boot key to select USB when needed (or change it back to USB in BIOS settings).

Comment: actually I thought about something like that the external disk is actually booted but the booting only redirects to the next booting step.